# Android Java code is not doing math correctly

Tags: java, android

I am having a very odd result in my Android program when adding two numbers. It is the test code I am using to find out what is going out:

```
private static final float yChannel[] = {12.0f, 8.0f, 4.0f, 0};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("Rectangles","y1: " + yChannel[0]+2.0f);
    Log.i("Rectangles","y2: " + yChannel[0]);
}
```

The LogCat result is:

```
y1: 12.02.0
y2: 12
```

I simply don't understand all the variables are float. My code is not working because it is not giving the correct result. I also tried cleaning Eclipse project.

Comment: The code is working as you wrote. If the result is bad, than you wrote it wrong.

Comment: What result were you expecting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"Rectangles","y1: " + yChannel[0]+2.0f
```

is string concatenation, as the first operand is the string.

try this

```
Log.i("Rectangles","y1: " + (yChannel[0]+2.0f));
```

or

```
float temp = yChannel[0]+2.0f;
    Log.i("Rectangles","y1: " + temp);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need brackets around the float calculations because the arguments are being converted to strings when added to the string